# jQuery UI Date Picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am showing the birthday option and have used the jquery ui date picker. The problem is that I want show past dates for example ***starting from 1950 till 2000*** but I don't know how to do that, i tried this but it did not work:

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: '-20Y',
    maxDate: '+1M +10D'
    });
```

Ref:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

**Update:**

Here is what, I am doing, you could fix that by updating the code there:

http://jsbin.com/uyake

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: new Date(1950, 0, 1) ,
    maxDate: new Date(2000, 11, 31),
    defaultDate: new Date(1950, 0, 1),
    yearRange: '1950:2000'
    });
```

Working Demo is [here:](http://jsbin.com/uyake/2)

Answer (score 1):

> This Will help display date range for a specific age

```
var age_limit = 20;
var inId = tag.id;
$("#datePicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1950:' + (new Date().getFullYear() - age_limit)
   });
$("#datePicker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
$("#datePicker").datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "drop" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date object as a value in your minDate and maxDate options, ex:

```
{ 
  minDate: new Date(1950, 0, 1),
  maxDate: new Date(2000, 11, 31) 
}
```

This is done according to: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mix up minDate and maxDate? Also - make sure every property but the last one ends with coma. Also make sure you didn't put two "minDate" there.

Comment: Yes iam sure i did it fine but still no luck